# Wrong UNIQUE column in SQLite with Android

Tags: android, sqlite, duplicates, unique

I want to prevent duplicates in my SQLite databse so I made one column `UNIQUE`. But strangely there is chosen the wrong column. Here is my DatabseAdapter:

```
public class ProjectsDBAdapter {

 public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
 public static final String KEY_PROJECTNAME = "projectname";
 public static final String KEY_ROUTERIP = "routerip";
 public static final String KEY_URL = "url";
 public static final String KEY_CALIMERO = "calimero";

 private static final String TAG = "ProjectsDBAdapter";
 private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
 private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

 private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "KNXTable";
 private static final String SQLITE_TABLE = "Project";
 private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

 private final Context mCtx;

 private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
  "CREATE TABLE if not exists " + SQLITE_TABLE + " (" +
  KEY_ROWID + " integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement," +
  KEY_PROJECTNAME + " TEXT UNIQUE," +
  KEY_ROUTERIP + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
  KEY_URL + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
  KEY_CALIMERO + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
  " UNIQUE (" + KEY_PROJECTNAME +"));";

 private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

  DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
   super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
   //invoked when the database is created, 
   //this is where we can create tables and columns to them, create views or triggers.
   Log.w(TAG, DATABASE_CREATE);
   db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
  }

  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
   //invoked when we make a modification to the database such as altering,
   //dropping , creating new tables.
   Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
     + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
   db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + SQLITE_TABLE);
   onCreate(db);
  }
 }

 public ProjectsDBAdapter(Context ctx) {
  this.mCtx = ctx;
 }

 public ProjectsDBAdapter open() throws SQLException {
  mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
  mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
  return this;
 }

 public void close() {
  if (mDbHelper != null) {
   mDbHelper.close();
  }
 }

 public long createProject(String ip, String name, 
   String url, String calimero) {

  ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
  initialValues.put(KEY_PROJECTNAME, name);
  initialValues.put(KEY_ROUTERIP, ip);
  initialValues.put(KEY_URL, url);
  initialValues.put(KEY_CALIMERO, calimero);

  return mDb.insertOrThrow(SQLITE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
 }

 public boolean deleteAllProjects() {

  int doneDelete = 0;
  doneDelete = mDb.delete(SQLITE_TABLE, null , null);
  Log.w(TAG, Integer.toString(doneDelete));
  return doneDelete > 0;
 }

 //---deletes a particular title---
 public boolean deleteTitle(String name) 
 {
    return mDb.delete(SQLITE_TABLE, KEY_PROJECTNAME + "='" + name+"'", null) > 0;
 }

 public Cursor fetchProjectsByName(String inputText) throws SQLException {
  Log.w(TAG, inputText);
  Cursor mCursor = null;
  if (inputText == null  ||  inputText.length () == 0)  {
   mCursor = mDb.query(SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
    KEY_PROJECTNAME, KEY_ROUTERIP, KEY_URL, KEY_CALIMERO}, 
     null, null, null, null, null); 
  }
  else {
   mCursor = mDb.query(true, SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
     KEY_PROJECTNAME, KEY_ROUTERIP, KEY_URL, KEY_CALIMERO}, 
     KEY_PROJECTNAME + " like '%" + inputText + "%'", null,
     null, null, null, null);
  }
  if (mCursor != null) {
   mCursor.moveToFirst();
  }
  return mCursor;
 }

 public Cursor fetchAllProjects() {

  Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
    KEY_PROJECTNAME, KEY_ROUTERIP, KEY_URL, KEY_CALIMERO}, 
    null, null, null, null,KEY_PROJECTNAME +" DESC");

  if (mCursor != null) {
   mCursor.moveToFirst();
  }
  return mCursor;
 }
```

}

and with this code I fill the database:

```
        Name = project_name.getText().toString();
        IP = router_ip.getText().toString();
        URL = url.getText().toString();
        dbHelper = new ProjectsDBAdapter(this);
        dbHelper.open();
        //TODO Name statt IP auf Duplikat überprüfen
        try {
            dbHelper.createProject(IP, Name, URL, "Edit");
        } catch (SQLiteException exception) {
            Log.d("SQLite", "Error"+exception.toString());
            exception.printStackTrace();
            duplicate_flag = 1;
        }
```

LogCat Output:

```
09-28 13:32:15.925: I/URL(22204): URL http://www.mokkapps.de/wp-admin/calimero.xml ist gültig!
09-28 13:32:15.925: I/Name(22204): Projektname ist Test
09-28 13:32:15.925: I/IP(22204): IP ist 1
09-28 13:32:16.000: W/AndroidParseXMLActivity(22204): Start
09-28 13:32:16.020: W/AndroidParseXMLActivity(22204): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/Test.xml: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
09-28 13:32:16.020: W/AndroidParseXMLActivity(22204):   at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:406)
09-28 13:32:16.020: W/AndroidParseXMLActivity(22204):   at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
09-28 13:32:16.020: W/AndroidParseXMLActivity(22204):   at de.bertrandt.bertrandtknx.CreateProject.parseXML(CreateProject.java:340)
09-28 13:32:16.020: W/AndroidParseXMLActivity(22204):   at de.bertrandt.bertrandtknx.CreateProject.save_project(CreateProject.java:291)
09-28 13:32:16.020: W/AndroidParseXMLActivity(22204):   at de.bertrandt.bertrandtknx.CreateProject.onOptionsItemSelected(CreateProject.java:108)
09-28 13:32:16.020: W/AndroidParseXMLActivity(22204):   at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2564)
09-28 13:32:16.020: W/AndroidParseXMLActivity(22204):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:984)
09-28 13:32:16.020: W/AndroidParseXMLActivity(22204):   at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
09-28 13:32:16.020: W/AndroidParseXMLActivity(22204):   at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:149)
09-28 13:32:16.020: W/AndroidParseXMLActivity(22204):   at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
09-28 13:32:16.020: W/AndroidParseXMLActivity(22204):   at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:613)
09-28 13:32:16.020: W/AndroidParseXMLActivity(22204):   at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:121)
09-28 13:32:16.020: W/AndroidParseXMLActivity(22204):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3644)
09-28 13:32:16.020: W/AndroidParseXMLActivity(22204):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14313)
09-28 13:32:16.020: W/AndroidParseXMLActivity(22204):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
09-28 13:32:16.020: W/AndroidParseXMLActivity(22204):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-28 13:32:16.020: W/AndroidParseXMLActivity(22204):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-28 13:32:16.020: W/AndroidParseXMLActivity(22204):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
09-28 13:32:16.020: W/AndroidParseXMLActivity(22204):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-28 13:32:16.020: W/AndroidParseXMLActivity(22204):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-28 13:32:16.020: W/AndroidParseXMLActivity(22204):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
09-28 13:32:16.020: W/AndroidParseXMLActivity(22204):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
09-28 13:32:16.020: W/AndroidParseXMLActivity(22204):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-28 13:32:16.020: W/AndroidParseXMLActivity(22204): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
09-28 13:32:16.020: W/AndroidParseXMLActivity(22204):   at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
09-28 13:32:16.020: W/AndroidParseXMLActivity(22204):   at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
09-28 13:32:16.020: W/AndroidParseXMLActivity(22204):   at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:390)
09-28 13:32:16.020: W/AndroidParseXMLActivity(22204):   ... 22 more
09-28 13:32:16.060: E/SKIA(22204): FimgApiStretch:stretch failed
09-28 13:32:22.590: I/URL(22204): URL http://www.mokkapps.de/wp-admin/calimero.xml ist gültig!
09-28 13:32:22.590: I/Name(22204): Projektname ist Test2
09-28 13:32:22.590: I/IP(22204): IP ist 1
09-28 13:32:22.635: D/SQLite(22204): Errorandroid.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
09-28 13:32:22.635: W/System.err(22204): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
09-28 13:32:22.640: W/System.err(22204):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_executeInsert(Native Method)
09-28 13:32:22.640: W/System.err(22204):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:113)
09-28 13:32:22.640: W/System.err(22204):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1838)
09-28 13:32:22.640: W/System.err(22204):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertOrThrow(SQLiteDatabase.java:1737)
09-28 13:32:22.640: W/System.err(22204):    at SQLite.ProjectsDBAdapter.createProject(ProjectsDBAdapter.java:88)
09-28 13:32:22.640: W/System.err(22204):    at de.bertrandt.bertrandtknx.CreateProject.save_project(CreateProject.java:283)
09-28 13:32:22.640: W/System.err(22204):    at de.bertrandt.bertrandtknx.CreateProject.onOptionsItemSelected(CreateProject.java:108)
09-28 13:32:22.645: W/System.err(22204):    at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2564)
09-28 13:32:22.645: W/System.err(22204):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:984)
09-28 13:32:22.645: W/System.err(22204):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
09-28 13:32:22.645: W/System.err(22204):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:149)
09-28 13:32:22.645: W/System.err(22204):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
09-28 13:32:22.645: W/System.err(22204):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:613)
09-28 13:32:22.645: W/System.err(22204):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:121)
09-28 13:32:22.645: W/System.err(22204):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3644)
09-28 13:32:22.645: W/System.err(22204):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14313)
09-28 13:32:22.645: W/System.err(22204):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
09-28 13:32:22.645: W/System.err(22204):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-28 13:32:22.645: W/System.err(22204):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-28 13:32:22.645: W/System.err(22204):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
09-28 13:32:22.645: W/System.err(22204):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-28 13:32:22.645: W/System.err(22204):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-28 13:32:22.645: W/System.err(22204):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
09-28 13:32:22.645: W/System.err(22204):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
09-28 13:32:22.645: W/System.err(22204):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

At the moment the exception is thrown if the routerip is duplicated, but I want to check the name.
Can anyone find my mistake? Can't be that dramatic but I cannot find the problem...

Comment: add here your full logcat please.

Comment: added logcat output to my mainpost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run the project first time with one column unique and then change it later then your change will not be reflected.Because table is already created and not going to be created again with the new structure.So if it is the case uninstall the app and run it again.You can also use sqlite browser to test the table

Answer (score 1):

If you did not change the Database version you will got this error because your all code is fine but the android database object think like it was the previous database so change the database version and check it again it will work on emulator and on real device you need to delete first app and then check it just above Rasel say